# How to inject a Presenter into a View (MVP pattern) using Dagger2

Tags: android, mvp, dagger-2

I want to build an Android app using the MVP pattern.

I have a fragment (the view) and a presenter class.

What I want is to basically inject the presenter into the fragment, and set the fragment as the presenter's view (via an interface that the view will implement)

How can I easily and correctly connect the 2 using dependency injection (with Dagger2)?

**Edit:**

In addition, I'd like the presenter to be a singleton, so it will be able to persist data & state across orientation changes

Comment: Have you considered Mortar https://github.com/square/mortar ?  or nucleus https://github.com/konmik/nucleus ?

Comment: Thanks @Emma, those libs look interesting. However, I'm trying to learn about using dagger2 and DI, and so I would still like to know what is a good way to implement MVP using Dagger2

Comment: I see.  Mortar uses dagger as view injection however mortar has its own view and presenter classes so you will not use fragment, though.

Comment: Thanks :) I would still like to know the answer to my question using dagger2 though

Comment: If you want to bind a presenter to the scope of the activity or the fragment, then you'll need either the scopes provided by Mortar, or you'll need a retained fragment, or you'll need singleton presenters which are a pain to get right. Dagger2 and orientation-surviving-scopes are not mutually exclusive, in fact, they are quite orthogonal. Mortar allows the retaining of the subscoped component with minimal hassle.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to define a presenter module:

```
@Module
class SearchPresenterModule {
    @NonNull
    private final SearchContract.View mView;

    SearchPresenterModule(@NonNull SearchContract.View view) {
        this.mView = view;
    }

    @Provides
    SearchContract.View provideSearchContractView() {
        return mView;
    }
}
```

Here's the example component:

```
@FragmentScoped
@Component(modules = SearchPresenterModule.class)
interface SearchComponent {
    void inject(SearchActivity activity);
}
```

And inject your presenter:

```
@Inject
SearchPresenter mSearchPresenter;

DaggerSearchComponent.builder()
            .searchPresenterModule(new SearchPresenterModule(searchFragment))
            .build()
            .inject(this);
```

Finally inject your presenter's constructor:

```
 @Inject
 SearchPresenter(@NonNull SearchContract.View view, @NonNull SearchRepository searchRepository) {
        this.mView = view;

        mView.setPresenter(this);
    }
```

Extra: Here's fragmentscoped annotation:

```
@Documented
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FragmentScoped {

}
```

You can check my example repo for MVP + DAGGER2
https://github.com/savepopulation/wikilight

Answer (score 0):

so the presenter is like

```
@Singleton
public class Presenter{
private View mView; ...
```

the view should be

```
public class View extends ...{
    @Inject
    protected Presenter mPresenter ...
```

Well, you just need a method in your module like

```
inject(View view)
```

and Dagger should take care of the rest like the singleton instance and the injection